# Enabling publishing infrastructure feature in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Hi can I enable publishing infrastructure feature in sharepoint 2010
Thanks

Comment: Because people find this page **when** doing the simple Google search - so it **is** worth it, regardless of aYus ignorance of good answers :)

Answer (score 18):

You need to activate Publishing Infrastructure in the Site Collection where you want to use Publishing.

Go to the Top level site of the Site Collection and choose Site Actions > Site Settings. On the Site Settings page in the Site Collection Administration column choose Site Collection Features.  Activate SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure Feature.

Then go back to the Site Settings page and choose Manage site features in the Site Actions column.  Activate the Sharepoint server Publishing Feature.

Now you can activate Publishing on any site in this site collection.  For other site collections repeat the process.

Comment: Thanx, this one helped me. Needed to add myself as (secondary) administrator before seeing the Site Collection Administration navigation. That is done within Central Administration.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Go to Site Settings - Site Collection Administration - Site collection features
Scroll down to SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure and click the Activate button .

I assume this is what you are looking for. If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

In order to see the Site Collection Administration section in the Site Setting you have to be Site Collection Administrator. If you are only the site owner, the Site Collection Administration option will not be available. Once you have that level of permission you can enable publishing Infrastructure. As Dung said go to Site Collection Administration - Site collection features.